# What file system(s) does LynxOS support?

Tags: unix

LynxOS documentation say that uses a "Unix-like" file system . It says you can mount devices as file system, but doesn't state which are supported (e.g. EXT3, EXT4, etc).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.lynuxworks.com/rtos/lynxos50features.php) as well as [this one](http://www.lynuxworks.com/rtos/lynxos.pdf), it supports the following:

> - Lynx Fast File system
> - Network File System (NFS)
> - RAM disk file system

Comment: A couple follow up questions:
 - Is Lynx Fast file system proprietary? I'm guessing from the name that it is.
 - Is a RAM disk really a file system? Wikipedia gives the impression that you can put a variety of file systems on a RAM disk.

Comment: @TylerS As for the RAM disk File system, I have no idea. For the Lynx Fast File system, I believe it's proprietary; the only thing I ever heard about it was that it was used in the space program.